# It changes the format when displaying the answer after a calculation

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JWTQk/29/)

Now the problem I have when you look at the jsfiddledemo is that if you enter in a number within one of the text inputs (in question 1), it does the calculation but it displays the answer in a different way in the column.

Lets say in the top text input you type in the number 2, then it should display "Marks Remaining 3", but instead it removes the "Marks Remaining" txt and just displays the number 3 (and not in bold also).

So my question is that why is it changing the format on the far end column when displaying the answer to the calculation?

Below is the jquery function:

Jquery:

```
    $(function () {
        //alert("here");         
        var questions = $('#markstbl td[class*="_ans"]').length - 1;

        //disable single entry
        for (var i = 0; i <= questions; i++) {
            if ($("[class*=q" + i + "_mark]").length == 1) {
                var t_marks = $("[class*=q" + i + "_ans]").html();
                //alert(t_marks);
                $("[class*=q" + i + "_mark]").val(t_marks)
                    .attr("disabled", "disabled");
                //$("[class*=q"+i+"_mark]").attr("disabled","disabled");
            }
        }

        //find each question set and add listeners
        for (var i = 0; i <= questions; i++) {
            $('input[class*="q' + i + '"]').keyup(function () {
                var cl = $(this).attr('class').split(" ")[1]
                var questionno = cl.substring(cl.indexOf('q') + 1, cl.indexOf('_'));
                var tot_marks = $(".q" + questionno + "_ans_org").val();
                //alert(tot_marks);
                var ans_t = 0;
                $("[class*=q" + questionno + "_mark]").each(function () {
                    var num = (isNaN(parseInt($(this).val()))) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).val());
                    ans_t += parseInt(num);
                });
                ans_t = tot_marks - ans_t;
                //alert(ans_t);
                //var fixedno = tot_marks;
                var ans = (parseInt(ans_t) < 0) ? tot_marks : ans_t;
                $(".q" + questionno + "_ans").val(ans);
                $(".q" + questionno + "_ans_text").html(ans);
            });
        }
    });​
```

Below is the dynamic HTML Table:

HTML:

```
  <body>
  <table border='1' id='markstbl'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>

        <th class='questionth'>Question</th>

        <th class='answerth'>Answer</th>

        <th class='answermarksth'>Marks per Answer</th>

        <th class='noofmarksth'>Total Marks Remaining</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <?php
      $row_span  = array_count_values($searchQuestionId);
      $prev_ques = '';
      foreach ($searchQuestionId as $key => $questionId) {
      ?>

      <tr class="questiontd">
        <?php
            if ($questionId != $prev_ques) {
        ?>

        <td class="questionnumtd" name="numQuestion" rowspan=
        "<?php echo $row_span[$questionId]; ?>"><?php
                echo $questionId;
        ?><input type="hidden" name="q<?php echo $questionId; ?>_ans_org" class=
        "q<?php echo $questionId; ?>_ans_org" value=
        "<?php echo $searchMarks[$key]; ?>" /><input type="hidden" name=
        "q<?php echo $questionId; ?>_ans" class=
        "q<?php echo $questionId; ?>_ans" value=
        "<?php echo $searchMarks[$key]; ?>" /></td>

        <td class="questioncontenttd" rowspan="<?php echo $row_span[$questionId]; ?>">
        <?php
                echo $searchQuestionContent[$key];
        ?></td><?php
            }
        ?>

        <td class="answertd" name="answers[]"><?php
            echo $searchAnswer[$key];
        ?></td>

        <td class="answermarkstd"><input class=
        "individualMarks q<?php echo $questionId; ?>_mark_0" q_group="1" name=
        "answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" /></td><?php
            if ($questionId != $prev_ques) {
        ?>

        <td class="noofmarkstd q<?php echo $questionId; ?>_ans_text" q_group="1"
        rowspan="<?php echo $row_span[$questionId]; ?>"><?php
                echo $searchMarks[$key];
        ?></td><?php
            }
        ?>
      </tr><?php
          $prev_ques = $questionId;
      }
      ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

UPDATE:

Below is what the page looks like when its first open:

[image]

Below you can see the change on the end column at the right hand side when I enter in a number in a text input and it does the calculation and display the answer on the end column:

[image]

Comment: please post demo in jsffiddle.net and modify php code to live html . Your link requires login

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah give me bout 15 mins and I will get on working for jsfiddle

Comment: @charlietfl I am struggling to convert the dynamic html into a standard sample html in jsfiddle. So what I have done is show some screenshots in what is happening. Hopefully this could be helpful :)

Comment: can pull html from source view in browser. Really not clear what the issue is. Put the html and javascript into jsfiddle.net

Comment: @charlietfl Oh yeah, did not think of that. Jsfiddle is included in question. I replaced the live demo link with the jsfiddle link

Comment: Don't try to fix it - at least not in the way you are proposing. Instead, make "Marks Remaining" the column header, then each cell in the column is quite rightly just a number. See **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWTQk/30/)**

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Thanks for the comment, I actually changed the layout to match the layout you have in the fiddle. Upvoted comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the following:

```
$(".q" + questionno + "_ans_text").html(ans);
```

You are replacing `<strong>Marks Remaining:<br/>5</strong>` with just a number. A simple solution would be to add another tag wrapping the number and only change the text of that tag. removeing the `strong` tag is why the format is different

```
<strong>Marks Remaining:<br/><span class="ans">5</span></strong>
$(".q" + questionno + "_ans_text span.ans").html(ans);
```

Or you can parse new html:

```
var answerText='<strong>Marks Remaining:<br/>'+ans+'</strong>';
$(".q" + questionno + "_ans_text").html(answerText);
```

Comment: Thank you, I went with the parse new html method but they both work. Thanks